# Where to buy posters?

Tags: starcraft-2

I watch a lot of Day9 TV, and I just decided to buy some cool and fancy StarCraft II posters, but Googling didn't return any usable results. Blizzard Store failed, because it just offers one poster, that is, in my opinion, not very cool.

Do you have any websites where I can order SCII (or Diablo III) posters with worldwide shipping (or at least just North America + Europe)?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The main place to buy Starcraft merchandise, after the Blizzard store, is Jinx, an official outlet for Blizzard merchandise. However their Starcarft 2 section (http://www.jinx.com/starcraft) does not seem to have posters, though this may change in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Goto [BlizzCon](http://us.blizzard.com/blizzcon/) and get posters there
- The [Blizzard Store](http://us.blizzard.com/store/details.xml?id=1100000246) offers the Cinematic Poster of Tychus Findlay
- On [ecrater](http://www.ecrater.com/search.php?cid=895364&keywords=starcraft+2&x=0&y=0), someone is offering two poster/banners
- [Ebay](http://shop.ebay.com/i.html?_nkw=starcraft+2+poster), as of this posting is offering 170 "Starcraft 2 Posters" which appear to be a collection of posters from BlizzCon and more cloth/banner posters
  [image]
  [image]

Comment: Oh man, now i want that one of the colossus :/

Answer (score 2):

They sell them at BlizzCon, but I haven't seen them anywhere else.